# Print binary tree level by level

Tags: java, beginner, algorithm, tree

Please critique:

```
public void printTree(Node head) {
    if (head == null)
        return;
    Queue<Node> q1 = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
    Queue<Node> q2 = new PriorityQueue<Node>();

    q1.add(head);

    do {
        while (q1.size() > 0) {
            Node element = q1.poll();
            System.out.print(element.data + " ");
            if (element.left != null)
                q2.add(element.left);
            if (element.right != null)
                q2.add(element.right);
        }
        System.out.println();
        while (q2.size() > 0) {
            q1.add(q2.poll());
        }
        q2.clear();
    } while (q1.size() > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `Node` type should really be generic with `Node<T>`, so that you could easily store a `Node<Integer>`, `Node<Double>`, `Node<BigInteger>`, `Node<String>`, etc.

---

The function `printTree` accesses no external state. As such, I'd recommend it be made a static function:

```
public static void <T> printTree(Node<T> head) {
```

---

When I see `Queue<Node>`, I imagine a LIFO data structure. Priority queues are not LIFO, so if you really want a priority queue, I'd actually say `PriorityQueue<Node> q1 = new PriorityQueue<Node>();` However, this is up to preference; in general, it is good form to use `Queue<Node>`.

On the other hand, you may be simply looking for a queue datatype. In that case, you want `ArrayDeque<Node>`.

---

> ```
> q1.size() > 0
> ```

Replace that with `!q1.isEmpty()`. It reads better.

---

> ```
> while (q2.size() > 0) {
>     q1.add(q2.poll());
> }
> q2.clear();
> ```

What you are doing here is actually simply

```
q1.addAll(q2);
q2.clear();
```

---

Putting this all together:

```
public static void <T> printTree(Node<T> head) {
    if (head == null)
        return;
    Queue<Node<T>> q1 = new ArrayDeque<>(); // Type name can be left out here Java 7+
    Queue<Node<T>> q2 = new ArrayDeque<>();

    q1.add(head);

    do {
        while (!q1.isEmpty()) {
            Node<T> element = q1.poll();
            System.out.print(element.data + " ");

            if (element.left != null)
                q2.add(element.left);
            if (element.right != null)
                q2.add(element.right);
        }
        System.out.println();

        q1.addAll(q2);
        q2.clear();
    } while (!q1.isEmpty());
}
```

---

There are several options for improvements once you reach here. One is to create a separate `Iterator<Node<T>>` for your nodes, then just iterate over the iterator printing each node. But I'd also prefer this code:

```
public static void <T> printTree(Node<T> head) {
    if (head == null)
        return;
    Queue<Node<T>> q1 = new ArrayDeque<>(); // Type name can be left out here Java 7+
    Queue<Node<T>> q2 = new ArrayDeque<>();

    q1.add(head);

    // while loops are more common; there is no change in functionality, but may be easier to read.
    while (!q1.isEmpty()) {
        for (Node<T> element : q1) { // This is a for each loop
            System.out.print(element.data + " ");

            if (element.left != null)
                q2.add(element.left);
            if (element.right != null)
                q2.add(element.right);
        }
        System.out.println();

        q1 = q2; // garbage collection isn't *too* expensive, and we get more expressive this way.
        q2 = new ArrayDeque<>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Only one queue required

If you loop over the number of elements at each level, you can use a single queue to solve the problem:

```
public void printTree(Node head) {
    if (head == null)
        return;

    Queue<Node> q = new ArrayDeque<>();

    q.add(head);

    do {
        int size = q.size();
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            Node element = q.poll();
            System.out.print(element.data + " ");
            if (element.left != null)
                q.add(element.left);
            if (element.right != null)
                q.add(element.right);
        }
        System.out.println();
    } while (q.size() > 0);
}
```

Also notice I used an `ArrayDeque` because as Justin pointed out, a `PriorityQueue` is inappropriate for this program.